# Problems with WinEdt 7.0

Tags: winedt

I'm a newbie here, so forgive me if it's not the right kind of question to be posted.

I've just updated to WinEdt 7.0 and I wonder where are the old good features I loved in my previous version.

Namely:

1. Accents. My old WinEdt was well-trained and knew how to translate into LaTeX some non-English words with accents like "aquí" ("here" in Spanish), so I would never bother to actually writing down the correct TeX code for this accent on the `i` letter. This was part of the Options menu in my old WinEdt, but now has disappeared. Someone knows how:

   - Allow me to write `á` on my `.tex` file and let WinEdt 7.0 to translate it to TeX jargon?
   - Even better: *with* or *without* actually changing `á` into `\'a` in my `.tex` file? (I have reasons for both possibilities: when sharing the file with a colleague `\'a` would be better; when running my grammar checker `á` would be appreciated.)
2. Delimiters. With my old WinEdt we were so happy... When I wrote `\begin{something}` it would automatically add `\end{something}` and I even knew the place in the "Options" menu to teach her to do it. But, again, this possibility has now disappeared in the "Options" menu of WinEdt 7.0. (as far as I can see). So: where is this now hidden in WinEdt 7.0? I would also like to train it to "double" things like `$`, or to close automatically some other delimiters as  (`[`, `{` and the like, without having to think about it twice).

All this is hidden, I guess, somewhere in the "help" manual of my WinEdt 7.0, but, I'm sorry, I'm unable to find it.

Thank you for your patience with this un-updated WinEdt user.

Comment: Please visit on the web site of WinEdt the support. They can help you and they knew their program ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you've upgraded from WinEdt 5.x...

Starting with version 6, old WinEdt interfaces for customizations are gone. Now it adopts a new 'philosophy'. All customizations can be done modifying appropriate scripts through the `Options Interface` accessible from the `Options` menu.

When you launch the above command you will see a docked form at the left of your WinEdt window:

[image: Options interface]

Each one of the items you find inside branches is relative to one of the WinEdt functionalities that can be customized. Double-clicking on it, the corresponding local script gets opened. Now you have to modify that script to apply your customizations.

When one of the customization scripts is opened, clicking on the `Help` button in the toolbar of the Options Interface leads you to the corresponding page in the manual, where you can find guidelines on how to customize it.

When you've finished, you have to click the button `Load Current Script` in the same toolbar to apply the changes (the first one on the left). Note that if you skip this step nothing will be changed in your configuration...

I suggest you to read the introduction at the 'WinEdt Configuration Manual' for more info.

---

Going back to your questions:

1 - WinEdt 7 is an Unicode editor, so the translations tables you refer to are not more necessary (although still available). Just add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

to your document and you will be able to write all characters (like á) and compile your document with them.

2 - To customize these things, you have to modify the item `Active Strings` in the Options Interface. All the things you've mentioned are there, they just need to be activated.

If you encounter any problem, you're welcome to write at the WinEdt Mailing List and there you will find people that have answers for all your questions.

---

BTW: since WinEdt 8 with folding capabilities has been released (no upgrade fee from version 7) why don't switch directly to it?

Comment: Ok, thank you karlkoeller: your answer helps a lot.